# Print Entire Content of Modal window

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui, modal-dialog, kendo-window

The Content of my Kendo UI kendoWindow object contains content that exceeds 1 printed page. Whenever I print the content of the modal window I can only print 1 page.

I have tried setting the height of a container object to a large number and still there is only 1 page in the print review.

Any advice on how to print the entire contents (when it exceeds 1 print page) of a modal window would be great.

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some investigation I determined that I needed below CSS for correct printing.

```
@media print
{
body > .k-window
    {
        display: block !important;
        position: relative !important;
        top: auto !important;
        left: auto !important;
        width: auto !important;
        height: auto !important;
        border-width: 0;
        box-shadow: none !important;
    }
}
```